What is the wave function for alpha decay?
I'm reading "Albert Einstein: Philosopher-scientist (Living Philosophers Volume 7 by Paul Arthur Schilpp)" (p. 668):

Then it is possible for us, following Gamow, to replace the rest of the atom by a space of atomic order of magnitude, surrounded by a closed potential energy barrier which, at a time t = 0 encloses the particle to be emitted. The radioactive process thus schematized is then, as is well known, to be described - in the sense of elementary quantum mechanics - by a $\psi$-function in three dimensions, which at the time t = 0 is different from zero only inside of the barrier, but which, for positive times, expands into the outer space.

I would like to see that $\psi$-function. I was not able to find it via web search, in wikipedia George_Gamow and Alpha_decay, the linked paper "Ronald W. Gurney & Edw. U. Condon (1928). "Wave Mechanics and Radioactive Disintegration" does not have it (it's free to read but it's rather short - one page), I was not able to obtain (found a pay-walled link) original paper "G. Gamow (1928). "Zur Quantentheorie des Atomkernes (On the quantum theory of the atomic nucleus)". Zeitschrift für Physik. 51".

Have you tried textbooks? This is a standard thing treated in most nuclear physics textbooks.

@naturallyInconsistent, on wiki Alpha_decay there is a link to "Gamow theory of alpha decay" (https://web.archive.org/web/20090224200050/http://www.phy.uct.ac.za/courses/phy300w/np/ch1/node38.html). But there is no psi function there. It starts with "the transmission coefficent T is obtained from 2nd year quantum mechanics as ".

I'm using "An Introduction to Nuclear Physics" by Cottingham and Greenwood as reference.
The alpha particle, upon being formed, is in a Coulomb potential due to the daughter nucleus. Therefore the radial part of the Schrödinger equation is ($Q$ is the heat of the reaction, equivalently, the energy)
$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2f}{dr^2}+\frac{2Z_de^2}{4\pi\varepsilon_0r}f=Qf. $$
Attempting the ansatz $f(r) = e^{\phi(r)}$, this reduces to
$$ \frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left[\frac{d^2 \phi}{dr^2} +\left( \frac{d\phi}{dr}\right)^2 \right] = \frac{2Z_de^2}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 r}-Q.$$
For sufficiently slow-varying potentials, the second derivative may be approximated as zero, and then you can write the solution directly as an integral. Knowing that $f=e^\phi$ and knowing that the Schrödinger equation is a second order differential equation, one may write $f(r)$ as the superposition of two exponentials of $\phi(r)$. Since the negative exponential falls off rapidly, it's possible to simply consider the positive one. Therefore, ultimately
$$f(r)= C \exp \left( \int_r^{r_c}\sqrt{\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}\left[\frac{2Z_d e^2}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 r}-Q\right]}dr\right).$$

Thank you. I guess r - radius from center? Is it a time-independent function (for time t>0)?

Yes, $r$ is the distance from the center. The function has trivial phasorial time dependence as this is a solution to the time independent Schrödinger equation.

That integral can be done analytically.  See, for example, here:  https://arxiv.org/abs/0812.2236

You can download G. Gamow's article "Zur Quantentheorie des Atomkerns" (Zeitschrift für Physik 51 (1928) 204) at this Website: Lecture Universität Saarland (Germany)
